# export git => svn

Tags: git, svn

When I received the task there was not any repository. And my lead asked me to send snapshots by mail.
I started development using git init. 
Now the project received repository - but svn one. 
Is it possible to commit into it whole my git commits with proper comments, diff's, etc?
If yes - help me please with commands.
If not - how to do it better?
just git clone my repo into svn local copy and svn add each dir?

thank you. 
I hope there is a way to reintegrate my git repo into svn and continue development (locally) with git. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool `git-svn` which allows bidirectional communication between a git repo and a svn repo.